# Need help in analyzing the time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

There is an algorithm which requires us to print all subsequences of the prime factors of a number.
For example, if the number is 6, we will print:

**{}, {2}, {3}, {2 3}**

Now the given constraint is that the prime factor of a number will not exceed 13.

The complexity is clearly **O(pow(2, prime factors of the number))**

Now, my doubt is:
Since we know that the number of primes less than or equal to 13 is just 6. This makes the worst time complexity **O(pow(2, 6))** which is clearly O(1). So, can we call the algorithm a constant time algo, since we already know all the constant values which are possible candidates for the time complexity?

Comment: But there are infinitely many numbers whose prime factors are all less than or equal to 13.

Answer (score 1):

Not so fast.

If `k = 2n2 * 3n3 * 5n5 * 7n7 * 11n11 * 13n13` then the number of subsequences is `(n2+1) * (n3+1) * (n5+1) * (n7+1) * (n11+1) * (n13+1)` and the average length of those sequences is `(n2 + n3 + n5 + n7 + n11 + n13)/2`  It is easy to put the bound that each of those terms is `O(log(k))`.  And from that, you can put an upper limit of `O(log(k)7)` on the size of the output.  (If `pnp ≈ k1/6` for each `p` then all 6 terms are simultaneously of that scale.)

If the number does not start factored, you have to add in the difficulty of factoring the number first.

Comment: Shouldn't *the average length of those sequences* be the sum of the `n_i` divided by `6` rather than `2`? (there are 6 primes here). This of course doesn't change the conclusions of your answer; it is just side observation.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia No, because that's the average exponent for a single prime across all sequences, and the exponents evenly from `0` to `n_i`.  That averaging is where the "/2" comes from.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the clarification!